# Prove or disprove the convergence of...

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I need help with the following problem, please help.

For positive real x. Let

$${ B }_{ n }(x)\quad =\quad { 1 }^{ x }+{ 2 }^{ x }+{ 3 }^{ x }+...+{ n }^{ x }$$

Prove or disprove the convergence of...

$$\sum _{ n=2 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { { B }_{ n }\left( \log _{ n }{ 2 }  \right)  }{ { \left( n\log _{ 2 }{ n }  \right)  }^{ 2 } }  } $$

Comment: You should first try to work this out for integer values. For instance $$1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + n = n(n+1)/2$$ and $$1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + \cdots + n^2 = n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$$ and $$1^3 + \cdots + n^3 = n^2 (n+1)^2 / 4$$ This would be a good start to determine the convergence of this series.

Comment: Also note that $\log_n(2) = ln(2)/ln(n)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$B_n(log_n 2)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^{\log_n 2}$. Since $n^{\log_n 2} = 2$ we have that $B_n(\log_n 2) \leq 2n$.

Consider the series $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac{2n}{n^2\log_2^2 n}=\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac{2}{n\log_2^2 n}$.

The latter converges by integral Cauchy test, hence the former converges by the comparison one.